# Hyperledger fabric: Cli Bash isn't able to connect to orderer; chaincodes not instantiating on channel

Tags: docker, tcp, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-container

Error:

> error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to
>   orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context
>   deadline exceeded

I'm getting this error when trying to start a private collection in Fabric.
Following the docs properly and everything at the basic level seems to work (creating first app, creating first network, and extending first network - have not tried upgrading network parts yet). But as I create the private collections feature, it stops precisely at this step.

This happens when I start the network, go into the peer container using `docker exec -it cli bash` and instantiate the chaincode on the peer (`peer chaincode install -n marblesp -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/marbles02_private/go/`) which works.

But when I instantiate it on the channel (`peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n marblesp -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" --collections-config $GOPATH/src/github.com/chaincode/marbles02_private/collections_config.json --connTimeout 30s`) it produces this error and I dont know how proceed further.

Can someone help me understand what's wrong here or how to get my chaincode instantiated on my channel because I have to get the private collections to work?

Its possible this question is related to some communication between different docker images as my orderer and peer are in different containers. My commands run in the peer container (atleast thats what I think) and its unable to talk to orderer container.

Here are kinematic screenshots:

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

This is my command: (`peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n marblesp -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.member')" --collections-config $GOPATH/src/github.com/marbles02_private/collections_config.json --connTimeout 30s`).

I get this without sudo:

```
Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

and with sudo I get

```
Error: error getting endorser client for instantiate: endorser client failed to connect to 0.0.0.0:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

and in sudo case, it doesn't even wait 30s, it shows error within ~2 seconds.

Comment: Hey @anon, did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue with my setup.